# How to protect router access (Router: W/TW Arris DG1670a)?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, router

I have a time warner dg1670a router/modem and I'm having an issue where someone is somehow attacking my account.

When I go to log into the modem at 192.168.0.1 it says I'm using incorrect password.

Even when I disconnect the coax and do a long hard reboot and use a complicated 20+ character password and I come back a day or two later it says my password is incorrect.

I'm at a loss as to what to do or try (before this happened I installed a fresh copy of win 7 x64 and was about to start installing games) and one of the things that popped up was "I need to update flash" which is bs.

I dont know if a fresh install will fix this.

I did try getting a new modem and am now at 20 mb from 200.

I've since installed HTTPS apps and don't get why 192.168.0.1 is not encrypted and I don't know if it matters that the generic login is admin, password that admin be changed though only TW central office can do it.

Since this started I've not been able to use my PC and am afraid of logging into to the wifi and contaminating my iPhone 6.

Should I buy a better modem/router?

Comment: google 'hijack router'. scroll down a bit, and you'll see a result by avast.com about changing your settings to avoid that. see if that will help.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided any evidence of being hacked other than your password does not work after while. Does it work immediately after you have set it to something complicated (20+ characters)?

I would suggest testing with a simpler password (10-12 characters) based on my following experience:

My modem/router has a maximum password length of 15 characters and **silently ignores the extra characters when setting the password, but not when logging in.** So if I set a password longer than 15 characters it appears to be set correctly but I can't log in with the full password, only the first 15 characters of it.

Your modem/router may have a similar limitation on password length.

Comment: unfortunately its not the issue, its not password related in any way, no matter how strong or often its changed when I login it tells me its incorrect, ive tried hard reboots and disconnecting coax and all of the above. Then it told me I need to update flash which was fake it looked not real and was bs most windows were grayed out.